# How to insert the jQuery-Mobile buttons with icon?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I've been trying to insert a Plus(+)ICON in my web page but it does not show up.
i don't know why or maybe i need a PICTURE of it so that it will show up ?

```
<a data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right">Save</a>
```

but it does not work fine.

Any suggestion on how i get it to appear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m4rjZ/

```
    $('[data-role="content"]').append('<a data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right">Save</a>');
    // Enhance new button element
    $('[data-role="button"]').button();
```